# mostrar imagenes en pdf (dompdf)

Tags: laravel, xampp, dompdf

estoy generando un reporte en formato pdf (trabajo con alravel 8 y dompdf) el cual debe mostrar algunas imagenes. Las imagenes estan almacenadas fisicamente en el path (storage/fotos/xxxx.jpg) y la ruta  esta en la base de datos asi: "fotos/3zulC95zxc4TBk2HhVZsnIW8B8M7qxC8WWHSVlQC.jpg", ahora bien, en la vista desde donde tengo el boton para generar el pdf puedo mostrar las imagenes asi:

@foreach ($imagenes as $imagen )

```
<a href="{{asset('storage/'.$imagen->ruta)}}" data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="Imagen Mantencion ID {{$ejecucion->id}}">
     <img src="{{asset('storage/'.$imagen->ruta)}}" height="150px" width="180px">
</a>
```

@endforeach

pero en el blade del pdf cuando trato de obtener las imagenes, se queda pensando y me arroja error: **Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded**

He cambiado las opciones en el php.ini y sigue igual, el html del pdf no tiene estilos, solo el html y el ciclo foreach para recuperar las imagenes. He leido que dompdf tiene problemas con asset(), pero probe tambien con:

```
<img src="{{ url('storage/'.$imagen->ruta) }}" alt="" title="" /> y me genera el mismo poblema....
```

Saludos a todos y agradecido de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede ocurrir algún problema al buscar el directorio de tus imágenes, las posibles soluciones a esto sería algo así:

> Si está en la misma carpeta que tu archivo:

```
<img src="{{ url('/storage/'.$imagen->ruta) }}" alt="" title="" />
```

> O también de esta forma:

```
<img src="{{ url('./storage/'.$imagen->ruta) }}" alt="" title="" />
```

> O si está fuera de la carpeta de tu archivo:

```
<img src="{{ url('../storage/'.$imagen->ruta) }}" alt="" title="" />
```